# Akka actor isn't receiving case class [Akka remoting] (serialization issue)

Tags: scala, akka

I have an application which runs an actor system with a supervisor that can receive messages via akka remoting. Messages that are sent from the remote actor system are case classes, example:

```
case class SupervisorStartChannel(channelName: String) extends SupervisorRequest

case class SupervisorShutdown() extends SupervisorRequest
```

Within my receive, I have the following:

```
def receive: Actor.Receive = LoggingReceive ({
    case SupervisorListChannels =>
      listChannels()

    case SupervisorReportComponents =>
      sender ! loadConfiguredComponents()

    case SupervisorStartChannel(channelName) =>
      sender ! startChannelByName(channelName)

    case SupervisorShutdown =>
      log.info("Shutdown received.")
      sender ! SupervisorAck
      context.system.terminate()

    case _ =>
      replayError(s"$supervisorName can't process an empty command.")

}: Receive) andThen metered.Receive
```

If I send a SupervisorShutdown from inside the same actor system where the supervisor is running, it enters the correct case, however when sending the SupervisorShutdown() from the remote system it enters the case _. While sending a SupervisorStartChannel(channel1) works perfectly.

EDIT: After running some tests I found that the issue comes from the serialization of that `case class SupervisorShutdown() extends SupervisorRequest`. Akka uses the default Java serializer for remoting and that is causing it.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you try to add brackets to your case clause: `case SupervisorShutdown() =>` or use object instead of case class: `object SupervisorShutdown`?

Comment: @dyrkin yes I did, and since internal messages (within the same actor system) do work, makes me believe this is an issue with remoting.

Comment: After additional tests I found that this is an issue with the serializations. ActorSystem -> ActorSystem messages are being serialized. And since that `case class SupervisorShutdown() extends SupervisorRequest` is serialized with the default Java serializer is not being properly received.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @dyrkin suggested, after running a couple tests, this was solved by using `SupervisorShutdown()` instead of `SupervisorShutdown`, and then matching also with the `SupervisorShutdown()`.